# Anchor Link does not jump to correct section

Tags: sharepoint-online

I already build a lexikon like this on another Sharepoint online page:
A / B / C / ....

By clicking on a letter it jumps to the right section on the Site.

Now I wanted to make another page like this but it does not work anymore.
Even tough I insert the correct links to the Letters it always only jumps to the first section (Heading). In this case "A". No matter on which link you click.

The link looks the same like on my other page, where it works (...aspx#d)

I dont know where the mistake could be.

Answer (score 0):

How did you create these links? Are these in a viki page like this(links can all work normally);

[image]

How about clicking "try link"? You could check whether it will go to the correct address.

---

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.